# how to count number of days in a month in tradingview?

Tags: pine-script

i want to count how many days were in a month and week for my further calculations in pine different months have different count of days so i am not getting a accurate results if i keep updating the previous count of days using a input function. Is there any function i can use so that i get the exact count of days in each month.
for example:
count of days in February month = 20
count of days in March month  = 21
and i need to multiply this with 5
so if i keep updating these values my previous calculation are inaccurate.
can any one tell me how to fix this.

Comment: Please pay attention to correct capitalisation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a homework question. We do not do the homework for you. Please ask your teacher.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
days_in_month = 31 - (((month - 1) % 7) % 2)
if month == 2
    leap_day = iff(year % 4 == 0, 1, 0)
    days_in_month := 28 + leap_day
```